# Oracle Query Optimisation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with this query , it takes more than 5 min to be finished.
Could you please help me to enhance it(adding index ,enhance the query...)
The first part of the query makes an update only if the second part contains at least one row.
I used Exists to check this condition.

Comment: Please show us the ORACLE execution plan of this query, to get an idea whats goin on.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should clean up the query. That an updatable record must match hasalternativecode$type_ = 'Issuer' and accesspoint_ = 10 has nothing to do with the EXISTS clause or the SET subquery. This is criteria on the table itself and belongs in the WHERE clause.

Then: I surmise the GROUP BY clause is a safety measure? You expect one record per identifier_ and provider_ and want an exception otherwise? If this is not the case then remove the GROUP BY clause, because the subquery must return exactly one record or none at all, never more.

As to optimiziation: One can only optimize when the table structure is known. This includes both the definition (primary key, foreign keys, types, not null columns etc.) and data (how many records per table; how often do we find 'Issuer' records in the table, how often access point 10; how often the two combined?). Then, with the help of the dbms' execution plan, one could think about how to optimize.

As a start: Think about how many records per table are relevant. How many 'Issuers' with access point 10? If these happen to be very few, say 2% of all records, then an index would be helpful. In that case: Is there an index on both columns? If not, create one. Then on to fi_tradableasset_: How many records with the looked up code do you expect? Again: Just 2%? Then: Is there an index on fi_tradableasset_.issuer$code_? And so on.

At last: If the whole table must be read you could always use a parallel hint, e.g. `UPDATE /*+parallel(prc_alternativecode_,4)*/ prc_alternativecode_ ...`. Depending on the machine and ist usage this can speed up such a statement immensely.

Comment: i want to thank you for your response ,  you mean i should remove the exists condition and i should add criteria to the where clause in the main part?

Comment: No. Remove `prc_alternativecode_.hasalternativecode$type_ = 'Issuer'` and `prc_alternativecode_.accesspoint_ = 10` from your EXISTS clause and from the SET subquery. Instead put them in your WHERE clause: `WHERE hasalternativecode$type_ = 'Issuer' AND accesspoint_ = 10 AND EXISTS (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would turn that into a `MERGE` statement, in order to remove the extra access of the tables required by the `EXISTS` clause of the `UPDATE` statement. Something like:

```
merge into table_tgt tgt
using (SELECT   t.issuer$code_,
                a.dateandtime_,
                a.mainentityid_,
                '10' accesspoint_,
                MAX (b.updatoruserid_) updatoruserid_,
                '1423566734151' updatedate_,
                b.provider_ provider$code_,
                'Issuer' || MAX (b.provider_) || MAX (b.identifier_) unicity_,
                MAX (cs.pk_) provider$pk_,
                'false' locked_,
                b.identifier_ alternativecode_
       FROM     table_a a,
                table_b b,
                table_cs cs,
                table_t t
       WHERE    a.accesspoint_ = 100
       AND      a.pk_ = b.cialinstrumentnotification$pk_
       AND      b.provider_ = cs.identifier_ (+)
       AND      b.entitytype_ = 'Issuer'
       AND      a.identifier_ = t.identifier_
       GROUP BY t.issuer$code_,
                a.dateandtime_,
                b.identifier_,
                b.provider_,
                a.mainentityid_)
  on (src.issuer$code_ = tgt.hasalternativecode$code_
      and (tgt.alternativecode_ != src.alternativecode_
           OR tgt.provider$code_ != src.provider$code_)
      AND src.dateandtime_ >= tgt.updatedate_
      and tgt.mainentityid_ = src.mainentityid_)
when matched then
update set tgt.accesspoint_ = src.accesspoint_,
           tgt.updatoruserid_ = src.updatoruserid_,
           tgt.updatedate_ = src.updatedate_,
           tgt.provider$code_ = src.provider$code_,
           tgt.unicity_ = src.unicity_,
           tgt.provider$pk_ = src.provider$pk_,
           tgt.locked_ = src.locked_,
           tgt.alternativecode_ = src.alternativecode_
where      tgt.hasalternativecode$type_ = 'Issuer'
and        tgt.accesspoint_ = 10;
```

N.B. Totally untested, so you should test and make sure you're getting the right results. I've removed the unnecessary `MAX()`s around the two columns appearing in the `group by` clause. I've also turned the join on the ent_codificationsource_ table into an outer join

Comment: Thanks, but i cant update a column referenced in the On clause (updateDate_) 'SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "TGT"."UPDATEDATE_"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause
*Action:
'